# Is there anyway I can specify the channel of a bluetooth service?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to create a bluetooth service with a random `UUID` is there anyway I can specify which channel this service should use? As far as I know the channel is bound to the UUID. 
For instance:

```
OBEX Object Push {00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}:12
```

This is the OBEX Object Push in the `android kernel` which has the UUID `00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` and channel `12`. For this service the channel remains static, why can't I make a service that has a static channel?

Answer (score 0):

you can make it like this.

private final String PBAP_UUID = "00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";

mSocket = mDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(ParcelUuid.fromString(PBAP_UUID).getUuid());

System will create socket on channel 12 according to your uuid.

using a static channel may fail if you connect to phones of other platforms.

Channel may be different but uuid is the same regardless of platforms,
system will find the right channel with the standard uuid.

Comment: the BluetoothDevice library used to be able to have the option of setting channels/ports
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0f42037/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java

Anyone know how the latest version of createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() can have its channel set to a known value?